# Using DISTINCT and COUNT together

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count, distinct

I have two different product_id with multiple keywords per each.
Following statement is not working:

```
SELECT distinct product_id, COUNT(distinct keyword) as keyword_sum FROM data;
```

Currently result looks like this:

```
product_id     keyword_sum
2              47
```

Desired result would look like this:

```
product_id     keyword_sum
2              26
3              21
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the column you want to be unique and then you can use aggregate functions like `count`on each element of the group.

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT(distinct keyword) as keyword_sum 
FROM data
GROUP BY product_id
```

Comment: note that implicit sorting with GROUP BY is deprecated as off MySQL version >= 5.6 so you need to use an explicit GROUP BY product_id ORDER BY product_id ASC or GROUP BY product_id ORDER BY NULL if you dont need/want the overhead of sorting.. this should make if future proof..

Comment: @RaymondNijland: Notg sure what you mean. Do you have a link about that?

Comment: @juergen d i've found some links well http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30477 and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html -> qoute  "Relying on implicit GROUP BY sorting in MySQL 5.6 is deprecated. To achieve a specific sort order of grouped results, it is preferable to use an explicit ORDER BY clause"... the main trouble is that MySQL is using an implicit ORDER BY with GROUP BY this is against the ANSI SQL terms and Oracle will change that old behavior in the future MySQL version 5.7 m12 will still have that deprecated old behavior not sure if the final release will have it also...

Comment: @RaymondNijland: The first link if from **2007** and yes, you should define a specific sort when you need one. That is true for all DB systems. But if you don't need a specific sort order then don'zt define one. It only costs performance so spare it if you don't need it. Of course ordering `by null` is stupid.

Comment: @juergen d the first link is indeed old (this an old Feature request indeed).. the second link is the most important one.. well MySQL is the only database engine i know what is using implicit sorting off results with an GROUP BY without using an ORDER BY.. i agree that `ORDER BY NULL` is an wierd or even stupid statement to disable the use off filesort but it is within the manual (second link) off MySQL